# how can i get the for each ground his owner and display it in table spring boot and angular

Tags: java, html, angular, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

In my Spring Boot project, this query returns the owner of a ground:
[image]

This is the API:
[image]

This is the service in the Angular frontend:
[image]

This is the component:
[image]

How can i call this API from Angular in order to display it in the `<span>` here?
[image]

I need to display the owner for each ground instead of showing all owners.
[image: here]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem or error you're having, ideally in an online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).